An inequality for integrals of analytic functions in unitary disk
Let $D := \{z \colon |z| < 1\}$ be the unitary disk, and let $\overline{D}$ be the disk together with its boundary. Show that for a function $f \colon \overline{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ analytic in $D$ and continuous in $\overline{D}$ the inequality
$$
 2 \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 \; dx \leqslant \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(e^{it})|^2 \; dt 
$$
holds.
I can't tell which tools does this problem require. My first intuition would be the maximum modulus theorem (but how could it be applied here?). These two integrals seem to be taken on homotopic paths, but that's no use. Any ideas? I'd appreciate any help.
